# How to use Xcode "move-line-up" shortcut on German keyboard of Macbook pro?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My Macbook pro has Germany keyboard layout. XCode 4 has a keyboart shortcut for "move-line-up": Option-Command-[, but I cannot do that, as on German keyboard layout, "[" can only be typed using Option-5. So if I type Option-Command-5, it means Option-Command-5.

I have also tried to change the key binding for that function in XCode preference to Option-Command-5, but then in Xcode editor that key binding does not work.

Is there any way to type Option-Command-[ using German keyboard of Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

You could try rebinding the action to a different key combination. To change this, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, then click the 'Key Bindings' section. Enter 'move line' in the search box and double click on a key combination to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using QWERTY layout for programming, especially Obj-C. Typing `{}` and `[]` are just no fun with a German keyboard layout.

Comment: Nah, I’m not really one for unconstructive answers… ;-) I have a German-layouted hardware keyboard myself. You can set a new virtual keyboard layout in System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Input Sources. In addition to `German`, I also have `U.S.`, and use `Opt-Cmd-Space` to switch between the two, e.g. when switching to programming from writing an e-mail in German. It might take some getting used to, but in the long run you might end up thanking me.

Comment: That's a workaround. But don't you need a keyboard cover like [this](http://www.kbcovers.com/servlet/Detail?no=231)? Or you have memorized the position of all US-layout keys?

Comment: Myself, I started using computers with a QWERTY layout, so my experience won’t be helpful for you. You might want to check out Keyboard Viewer for reference when you get stuck. It’s available from the Input Sources menu bar item.I’ve had other (German) programmer friends do the transition, who all were very very happy they did.

Comment: Are you serious Apple? First, add a virtual keyboard - then switch to it via three keys - then then press another three keys?

Answer (score 0):

Apple revised the keyboard shortcuts in Xcode some time ago. And non-American keyboard layouts are now taken into account.

Line Up: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Ö</kbd>

Line Down: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Ä</kbd>